# iOS - a NIB's view used across storyboards (for design & animation logic)

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface-builder, storyboard, xib

I have a iOS 5 project nearly completed, but there's one View missing everywhere which is the same. It's an alternative to the standard NavigationBar, you can go "back" in the navigation hierarchy with a swipe and it's animating nicely.

Ok, because it's hard to do the layout by code I created the empty IB document (HeaderView.xib) where I have a view containing subview and etc.
I had the animation code before so I just created a UIView subclass ("HRAnimationView") (and wrote the name of it in the xib's inspectors "Custom Class" field, also hooked up the subviews to outlets) with a method:

```
- (void)loadAnimation {…}
```

and a second one (this is the delegate-method for finished animations):

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString*)animationID finished:(NSNumber*)finished context:(void*)context {}
```

...this is where all the animation stuff happens and calling itself over and over till it's finished...

In the storyboard I have a subview with exact the same dimensions (and the outlet for it) and wanted to load the XIB (in the viewDidLoad-method of the corresponding controller) with:

```
NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];

HRAnimationView *view;

for (id object in bundle) {        
    NSLog(@"%@",object);
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        view = (HRAnimationView *)object;
}

self.headerView = view;
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[view loadAnimation];
```

BUT the headerView is EMTPY!! (also UIView *view didn't worked, nor owner:self.headerView)

…the Log just gives me:

```
<HRAnimationView: 0x3f1890; frame = (0 0; 240 49); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x3f18d0>>
```

…

WHAT IS the problem?? There's also no compilation failure!

I don't get it, why is the xib TOTALLY worthless in my case?!

Comment: Shouldn't isKindOfClass be checking for HRAnimationView instead of UIView

Comment: Hmm.. Thx, I'll check this. But shouldn't it work as HRAnimationView is a subclass of UIView?

Comment: It should, but I think that you want to make sure that it is the correct class to get expected behavior....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

I created a new ViewController and checked the "create with xib" box and deleted the view of the xib and copy&pasted the already set up view in there and in the ViewController I put the animation code in viewDidLoad.

Then loaded the hole thing in the viewDidLoad-method of each storyboard ViewController with:

```
UIViewController *ctrl = [[UIViewController alloc] initwithNibNamed:@"HeaderView"];
[self.headerView addSubview:ctrl.view]
```

(headerView is a IBOutlet to a view in every Storyboard so, that's basically the only thing to setup, NICE!)

1. another possibility would be:
   [Add subview using storyboard without external xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303101/add-subview-using-storyboard-without-external-xib)
2. or: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=749544

Looks like a Xib is useless without a corresponding ViewController, but should (strange.. whatever). 
But thanks for your responses, hope someone now can find this if he/she has the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

> NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];

after the above statement... try adding this

```
[self.headerView = [bundle objectAtIndex:0]
```

this should solve the problem